# php date format returns 01-01-1970

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my php code I insert some data in my database. One them is the date. I want to be displayed in the format of 27-08-2016 but I get back 01-01-1970

This is my code.

```
<?php 
include("./init.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $post_game = $_POST['game'];

 $time = strtotime($_POST['date']);

 $post_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($time));

if($post_game==''){

    echo "<script>alert('Please fill in all fields')</script>";
    exit();
    }
else {

    $insert_game = "insert into last_game (game,date) values ('$post_game','$post_date')";

    $run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$insert_game); 

        echo "<script>alert('Post Has been Published!')</script>";

        echo "<script>window.open('index.php?last_game_details','_self')   
   </script>";

     }

   }

?>
```

The crucial line is:

```
 $post_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($time));
```

and my php version is:**5.6.23**

Comment: strtotime failed, returned boolean false, which got type-cast to integer 0, which is Jan 1/1970. You are vulenrable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), all of your code simply ASSUMES nothing can ever fail, and now you're suffering for it. Never **EVER** assume success. always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Side note, fix the SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: in addition to this why are you inserting the `date` as a non `date` object into your database, date format should be `Y-m-d` for insertion into your database

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use  Now() in query to insert current date. NOW() returns the current date and time.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $post_game = $_POST['game'];

 $time = strtotime($_POST['date']);

 $post_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($time));

if($post_game==''){

    echo "<script>alert('Please fill in all fields')</script>";
    exit();
    }
else {

    $insert_game = "insert into last_game (game,date) values ('$post_game',NOW())";

    $run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$insert_game); 

        echo "<script>alert('Post Has been Published!')</script>";

        echo "<script>window.open('index.php?last_game_details','_self')   
   </script>";

     }

   }

?>
```

To retrieve your required format of date use php

```
`echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d ");`
```

Comment: That's good. I put a sample date and gave me this. 2016-07-18 19:14:18. But I want to take out the time.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $time = strtotime($_POST['date']);
    ^-integer             ^---string

$post_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($time));
                                ^^^^^^^---useless duplicate call, since you JUST did this anyways
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
 $time = strtotime($_POST['date']);    
 $post_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($time)); //why call strtotime again?
```

The 2nd time you call `strtotime`, you're feeding it a timestamp (the result of the first call), but it expects a date string. As a result it cannot parse the input and it returns an invalid time.  Just replace the two lines above with:

```
 $time = strtotime($_POST['date']);    
 $post_date = date("d-m-Y", $time);
```